# BeanCreationException with Spring Autowiring

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration, dialect

I am trying to use @Autowired, but I always receive the same exception:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserService com.logicart.vending.controller.user.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAO com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserService com.logicart.vending.controller.user.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAO com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAO com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAO com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserServiceImpl.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 60 more
```

User DAO:

```
import java.util.List;


import com.logicart.vending.user.model.User;

public interface UserDAO {

        public void addUser(User User);
        public List<User> getAllUser();
        public int deleteUser(Integer UserId);
        public User getUser(Integer userId);
        public User getUserByName(String userName);
}
```

DAO IMPL:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User User) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(User);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM dbo.usuarios").list();
    }

    @Override
    public int deleteUser(Integer UserId) {
        Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE dbo.usuarios WHERE id_usuario = :idUser");
        query.setParameter("idUser",UserId);
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(Integer userId) {

        Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM dbo.usuarios WHERE id_usuario = :idUser");
        query.setParameter("idUser",userId);
        List<User> users = query.list();
        if(users.size()>0)
            return users.get(0);
        else
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public User getUserByName(String userName) {

        Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM dbo.usuarios WHERE usuario = :userName");
        query.setParameter("userName",userName);
        List<User> users = query.list();
        if(users.size()>0)
            return users.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Service:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.logicart.vending.user.model.User;

public interface UserService {
    public void addUser(User User);
    public List<User> getAllUser();
    public int deleteUser(Integer UserId);
    public User getUser(Integer userId);
    public User getUserByName(String userName);
}
```

service IMPL

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User User) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            userDAO.addUser(User);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO falta implementar la clase de las excepciones
            try {
                throw new Exception("INSERT ERROR"+ErrorCode.ERROR_CODE_INSERT);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return userDAO.getAllUser();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO falta implementar la clase de las excepciones
            try {
                throw new Exception("GET_ALL_USER ERROR"+ErrorCode.ERROR_CODE_INSERT);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int deleteUser(Integer UserId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return userDAO.deleteUser(UserId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO falta implementar la clase de las excepciones
            try {
                throw new Exception("DELETE ERROR"+ErrorCode.ERROR_CODE_INSERT);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User getUser(Integer userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return userDAO.getUser(userId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO falta implementar la clase de las excepciones
            try {
                throw new Exception("GET USER"+ErrorCode.ERROR_CODE_INSERT);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User getUserByName(String userName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            return userDAO.getUserByName(userName);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO falta implementar la clase de las excepciones
            try {
                throw new Exception("GET_USER_BY_NAME"+ErrorCode.ERROR_CODE_INSERT);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class userController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap map) 
    {
        map.addAttribute("userList", userService.getAllUser());

        return "editEmployeeList";
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

}
```

employee-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.logicart.vending.controller" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.logicart.vending.user.dao.UserDAOImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userService" class="com.logicart.vending.user.service.UserServiceImpl"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have tried many different attempts but do not know what to do.

Comment: I think you need to provide                                    @Service("userService") on
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService

Comment: Does it say anything to you `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set' not set` ?

Comment: I am write "@Service(value= "UserService")" and I have the same problem... tahks

Comment: yes, the dialeg is in a docuemnt... jdbc.properties ,  in this document I have all configuration for conection to BBDD

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server you are using ? Dialect differs for different versions. check this url http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects

Comment: I use SQL server 2008, but I resolve the problem... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your root cause is here:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set' not set

And it is from this config:

```
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
```

So, it looks like your `<property-placeholder>` doesn't see `jdbc.dialect` property or you don't have it at all.

Can you fix this issue or explain why it is like that ?

Comment: yes... I'am a file with config for connect to BBDD:
jdbc.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Vendin
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=Descartes130

and in the xml, with JSTL i write this "dialect"...
.....
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
.....

is good idea??

Comment: Right, it's correct. But do you have a `<property-placeholder>` definition for your properties file ?

Comment: like <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
 </bean>

Comment: If you don't have `<property-placeholder>` there is no reason to use placeholder (`${...}`)

Comment: thanks... now detect the dialect.. but.. no found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Looks like it is a different question... However, can you show the new StackTrace after fix the issue for `dialect` ?

Comment: sorry, I resolve the error... after the <property-placeholder>, the error was for a jar...